# How to invoke Azure batch service from Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created Azure batch service which processes some logic. I want to invoke Azure batch from Release pipeline as empty process. Is it possible ?

Azure batch service is written in Azure batch SDK in side .net console application

Or I want To invoke Azure functions from Azure pipelines which will indirectly call Azure batch.

Please suggest

Comment: You can have a try for calling the REST API, please see [ Azure Batch Service REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/) for details.

Comment: But how do I call them from Azure pipelines ?

Comment: I know this is an old question. But i have an Azure Batch being called by Azure function. It seemed the right way to include Azure Batch is a PAAS world.

Answer (score 0):

Using YAML in Azure Pipelines you can call an Azure Function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops

From an Azure Function you are able to access Azure Batch Client using the azure Batch SDK

I actually use 3 Azure Functions, One to create the batch (Pool and Jobs), one to monitor (The task being complete in the Job) and one to clean up (Delete the Pool) once it completes.

```
[FunctionName("StartBatch")]
public static async Task StartBatch([QueueTrigger("batchprocess", Connection = "QueueStorage")] Batch batch, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Function processed a request for {batch}");

    int batchDelay = Int32.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BatchDelay"));
    string batchAccountUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BatchAccountUrl");
try
{
    Task<string> tokenProvider() => Utils.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync();
    using (var client = BatchClient.Open(new BatchTokenCredentials(batchAccountUrl, tokenProvider)))
    {
        Infrastucture.BuildBatchInfrastructure(client, batch, log);
        await client.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync(batch.JobName, Job.AddTasksAsync(batch, log).Result);
    }
    log.LogInformation($"Waiting {batchDelay} minutes until starting montioring the batch {batch}");

    await Utils.AddMessageToQueue(batch, batchDelay, "monitorbatch");
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    log.LogError("Issue ", exp.StackTrace);
    await Utils.AddMessageToQueue(batch, 0, "failedbatchprocess");
}
```

}